# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3: Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been doing this for days now, still got this error even though I already tried different data type conversion from nvarchar to float.. I can't update the data types of the table because I just used someone databases.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   [FIELD1]  CODE
  , 'TPZPC-' + [FIELD30] + '-' + [FIELD2] AS "TP_ID"
  ,[FIELD30] CUSTOMER_CODE
  ,[FIELD2]  SHIP
  ,[FIELD4]  CUSTOMER_NAME
  ,[FIELD7]  CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
  ,[FIELD8]  CUSTOMER_ADDRESS2
  ,[FIELD9]   
  , B.PROVINCE  
  , B.CITY    
  , B.REGION
  , B.CUSTOMER_CLASS
  ,[FIELD14]  QUANTITY_ORDERED
  , CASE WHEN [FIELD35] =1
         THEN [FIELD15] * -1
         ELSE [FIELD46] 
    END  AS QUANTITY_SHIPPED
  ,[FIELD41]  SELLING_UOM
  , CASE WHEN [FIELD35] =1
         THEN [FIELD42] *-1
         ELSE [FIELD42] 
    END  AS SALES_AMOUNT
  ,[FIELD44]  PD_CODE
  ,[FIELD20]  DETAILMAN_CODE
  , CASE WHEN [FIELD46] LIKE '%-' 
        THEN -(CAST(REPLACE([FIELD46],'-','') AS FLOAT))  
        ELSE   CAST([FIELD46] AS FLOAT) 
    END  AS FINANCIAL_TRADE_DISCOUNT
  , CASE WHEN [FIELD35] =1
         THEN [FIELD25] * -1
         ELSE [FIELD25] 
    END  AS NET_AMOUNT
  ,[FIELD51]  GROSSSALESVATEX
  ,B.CUSTOMER_GROUP
  ,B.COMBINEDNAME   
  , CASE WHEN  [FIELD35] = 2
         THEN  0
         ELSE  ROUND((CAST( [FIELD46] AS FLOAT ) /1.12 ) * [FIELD14],2) 
    END  AS TRADEDISCOUNT
  , CASE WHEN  [FIELD35] = 2
         THEN  0
         ELSE  ROUND((CAST( [FIELD14]*[FIELD16] AS FLOAT  ) /1.12) ,2) 
    END  AS GROSS_SALES_VATEX
    FROM  DAILYSALES  A
    LEFT JOIN DIST_CUSTOMERS B
    ON 'TP' + [FIELD30] + '-' + [FIELD2]  = B.TP_ID
    AND A.FIELD30 = B.CUSTOMER_CODE
    AND A.FIELD2 = B.SHIP_TO_CODE
    AND B.CUSTOMER_GROUP NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Comment: what is the values in column field ? try to replace comma from value .. something like "REPLACE([FIELD46],',','')"

Comment: The value is the reverse negative like 453- , 3- .. I just first move the negative sign to front then convert it to float so that I can manipulate the data

The data type of FIELD46 is nvarchar

Comment: you need to replace '-'  to all fields when you try to convert to float !.. for example line : ROUND((CAST( REPLACE([FIELD46],'-','') AS FLOAT ) /1.12 )

Comment: Try the concatenations with `CONCAT()`, rather than `+`.

Comment: Also, do you really want a `float`, which is an imprecise datatype? `decimal` is almost always better.

Comment: Is the syntax of -1 * (CAST(REPLACE([FIELD46],'-','') AS FLOAT)) valid?

Comment: @HoneyBadger thanks for the tip. I will change the data type to Decimal

Comment: What was the result of `CONCAT`? This [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) *implicitly converts all arguments to string types before concatenation*. Also, error indicates line 3 is the issue `'TPZPC-' + [FIELD30] + '-' + [FIELD2] AS "TP_ID"` if this SQL is not part of a larger one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simplify the code to isolate the problem.  *Presumably* it is due to one of the explicit conversions.  However, similar errors can also occur with implicit conversions.

If the explicit conversions are causing the error, you can replace them with `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`.  For instance:

```
TRY_CAST(REPLACE([FIELD46], '-', '') AS FLOAT)
```

If you want to investigate further, determine where the conversions fail.  Repeat this for each column you are explicitly converting:

```
select x.*
from x -- whatever is the right table
where try_convert(float, field46) is null and field46 is not null
```

This might make it obvious what the issue is.  Or you can ask a new question with a simpler query and sample data.